# How can i read a json file in chromium source code using chromium in-built json parser

Tags: json, chromium

I am trying to read a JSON file in my browser based on Chromium source code.

I came to know that Chromium has an in-built JSON parser.

How can I use this parser to retrieve `url` from the following JSON file?

```
{
    "url": [
       "in.search.yahoo.com",
       "encrypted.google.com",
       "in.yahoo.com",
       "www.google.co.in",
       "mail.google.com",
       "www.yahoo.com",
       "www.yandex.com",
       "www.bing.com",
       "duckduckgo.com",
       "www.epicsearch.in"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is not valid JSON. Where are the commas between the array elements?

Comment: Sorry!! it was a typo.But the main problem is how can i read this file using chromium library??

Comment: Do you want to do this with JavaScript (i.e., `JSON.parse`), or do you mean you want to use the Chromium parser to do this in a lower-level language, like C?

Comment: I want to use chromium parser to do in c or c++

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/base/json/json_reader.h&sq=package:chromium&type=cs.

Comment: I know this module but here,read function accepts string and return a value pointer.But i want to read this file and further how can i manipulate the value pointer to retrieve url?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/base/json/json_file_value_serializer.h&sq=package:chromium&type=cs

Comment: See also https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/base/values.h&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&rcl=1375123569&l=53. You need to call GetAsDictionary, then GetList with path='url', then iterate through the list and convert values to strings.

Comment: are you saying something like this?                                Json reader js=new jsonreader();                                    value * ptr=js.read(); and then ? could you please elaborate? I am a fresher in the field.